# Android handwriting chinese character recognition SDK

Tags: android, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to add handwriting chinese character recognition to my app. I am looking for something like this, but for Android:

http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/mouse.html

Is there any free handwriting chinese character recognition SDK for Android ?

Thanks !